# OpenPyxl Module Needed For DataFrames?

Tags: python, excel, bash, pandas

I'm trying to write a series to an excel file with the with the code below:

```
appIdSeries.to_frame(name='excelFile').to_excel(excelFile, sheet_name='sheetName')
```

But I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named openpyxl
```

I installed the pandas module with the bash command below:

```
sudo yum install python-pandas
```

Do I also need to install the `openpyxl` module write `Data Frames` to excel files? Obviously, I need it to write `series` to excel files.

Comment: `pandas` uses 3rd party modules for writing excel files so yes you'd need whatever dependencies are required

Comment: @EdChum I thought dependencies were automatically installed. Is that not the case?

Comment: unfortunately no, certainly in my case I've always had to install them myself, the thing is that as far as I remember there are different python excel modules that pandas uses depending on the excel extension type `.xls` versus `.xl` so these must be installed separately

Comment: Would you possibly know the syntax for install `openpyxl` on a RHEL box?

Comment: Sorry I don't, the docs seem to indicate that it uses `xlrd` but I can't help you with how to install on red hat